# Feeding external datataset in TensorFlow

Tags: python, dataset, tensorflow

i'have successfully tested the simple model of mnist classifier available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners

Now, i'm trying to run a similar model with external data, that i've used to train classifiers in python.

The dataset i'm using consist of the matrix X(11527 by 1200) containing the pixels values for 11527 images and Y(1200 by 26) containing the one hot encoded labels.

The problem i'm facing is that given the new data, the weights aren't changing with the iterations, and i'm stuck on a single accuracy value of 10,945 no matter how much iterations the system perform.

original code, from tensor flows website(this one works fine):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
primeiro programa feito com a biblioteca tensorflow do google
rede neural simples com objetivo de identificar caracteres
"""
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True) #importaçao do database MNIST

### montagem do "Graph" - "arquietura da rede" - ###########################################

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])  #placeholder representam os dados que irao entrar no sistema
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))  #pesos
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))      #bias
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)  #y function
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y)) #cost function
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)  #configuraçao do treinamento

############# INICIO DO TREINAMENTO #########################

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()  
sess = tf.InteractiveSession() 
sess.run(init)  #inicializa a sessao 
for i in range(1000): #loop de treinamento
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

################################################3#####
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)) #calculo da taxa de acerto
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print "taxa de acerto"
print sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})

#####################################################

#rotina de transformaçao de imagem para tensor (,784)
img = cv2.imread('digit.png',-1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28)) 

np.reshape(img, 784)
imgtensor = np.reshape(img, 784) #tensor de saida

print "caractere reconhecido"

predictvec = (y.eval(feed_dict={x: [ (imgtensor) ]})) #previsao de saida
a = sess.run(tf.arg_max(predictvec,1))
print(a+1) 
cv2.imshow('resized',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

code using external dataset (this one does not work)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Mar 12 18:49:42 2016

@author: rachillesf
"""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

## PREPARAÇÂO DOS DADOS#######################################################

#carregando dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt('char8k.txt', dtype='float', comments='#', delimiter=",")
Y = np.asmatrix( dataset[:,0] ) 
X = np.asmatrix( dataset[:,1:1201] )
m = 11527
labels = 26

# transforma y em uma matriz 11527x26
Yt = np.zeros((m,labels))

for i in range(0,m):
    index = Y[0,i] - 1
    Yt[i,index]= 1

Y = Yt
Y = np.asmatrix(Y)
Y = np.asanyarray(Y)
X = np.asanyarray(X)

### montagem do "Graph" - "arquietura da rede" - ###########################################

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1200])  #placeholder representam os dados que irao entrar no sistema
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,26])
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1200,26], stddev=0.001))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([26]))      #bias
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)  #funçao de y
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y)) #cost function
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)  #configuraçao do treinamento

############# INICIO DO TREINAMENTO #########################

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()  
sess = tf.InteractiveSession() 
sess.run(init)  #inicializa a sessao 
for i in range(100): #loop de treinamento
  print(i)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: X, y_: Y})

################################################3#####
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)) #calculo da taxa de acerto
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print "taxa de acerto"
print sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X, y_: Y})
```

Comment: Are your weights changing? Is your cost changing? Could be an issue of bad learning rate. Another debugging technique to reduce your dataset to a single example and make it work for it

Comment: the weights aren't changing, needer the cost.

Comment: i've train using a full dataset, minibath, and 1 example per iteration, and the results are the same

Comment: You could look at your gradients (https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/train.md#Processing-gradients-before-applying-them), if gradients are zero could be some problem with your data (ie, maybe it's not correctly one-hot encoded)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your weights and bias are initialized as zeros (check pesos and bias).
You should initialize bias to 0.1 and weights to a normal distribution.